# Defining a functional operator's "result" via an expression stored in a variable is not working

Tags: procedure, maple

I am struggling to figure out why the following two ways of defining a simple functional operator (https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=operators/functional&term=-%3E) are not equivalent. I have added a simple example below. How do I define the "result" via an expression stored in a variable as in the latter example? I am new to Maple.

```
# This works fine
f := (x, y) -> y^2 + x^2;
f(1, 2); 

# This does not work when I store the "result" expression in a variable first                              
temp := x^2 + y^2;
f := (x, y) -> temp;
f(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common source of confusion.

In your second example the formal parameters `x` and `y` of your procedure have no connection to the names `x` and `y` present in the expression assigned `temp`.

The usual way to accomplish the second example is to use the `unapply` command.

```
temp := x^2 + y^2;

                2    2
       temp := x  + y 

f := unapply(temp, [x,y]);

    f := proc (x, y) options operator, arrow; y^2+x^2 end proc

f(1, 2);

          5
```

One more general (and also more advanced) approach is to substitute into a template with the expression(s) containing the matching names. Eg,

```
g := subs(__dummy=temp,
      (x,y)->__dummy);

    g := proc (x, y) options operator, arrow; y^2+x^2 end proc

g(1, 2);

          5
```

Comment: Hello @acer, thanks for the solution. Both works fine for me and are simple to state. Out of curiosity do you have an opinion about which of the approaches is the better practice to use?

Comment: Unless you need the `subs` way you should use the `unapply` way, which is more usual, terser, and more easily and immediately understood by your instructor, your colleagues, and (3 months from now) yourself.